# How to set a property which is observable but not run observable function for few cases in EmberJS

Tags: ember.js

Is there anyway we can avoid running observable code in few cases?

**How i tried?**
The only way i found to avoid is by adding new properties to the view as flags which will if checked before running the observable method code.

This is the basic [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/codejack/7TueU/3/) link am providing with basic observer functionality
**HTML**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
  {{view MyApp.MyContainerView name="Santa Claus"}}
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="foo">
  {{view.testProp}}
</script>
```

**JS**

```
MyApp = Ember.Application.create({
    autoinit: false
});

MyApp.router = Ember.Router.create({
    root: Ember.Route.extend({
        index: Ember.Route.extend({
            route: '/'
        })
    })
});

MyApp.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({});

MyApp.MyContainerView = Em.ContainerView.extend({
    childViews: ['foo'],

    foo: Em.View.extend({
       testProp: 100,
  testPropObservable: function(){
    console.log("Prop Observed");
  }.observes('testProp'),
        init: function() {
            this._super();
            this.set('testProp', 200);//i want to avoid obeserver here
        },
        templateName: 'foo'
    })
});

MyApp.initialize(MyApp.router);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One alternative is to add/remove observers at runtime. Given the above example, you can prevent observer from being fired during init() by calling `this.addObserver` after the value has been initialized

```
    foo: Em.View.extend({
       testProp: 100,
       testPropDidChange: function(){
         console.log("Value changed to: ", this.get('testProp'));
       },
       init: function() {
         this._super();
         this.set('testProp', 200);//i want to avoid obeserver here
         this.addObserver('testProp', this.testPropDidChange)
        },
        templateName: 'foo'
    })
```

See this jsfiddle for a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/NSMj8/1/

There is a good overview of observers in the ember guides: http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/observers/

More info on how to add/remove observers is available in the API docs for Ember.Observable: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Observable.html

Comment: Yeah, you were just faster :), +1 BTW :)

Comment: that code was just an example to work on it..i do agree that we can add observer during initialization..i wanted to know if there is anyway we can avoid the call to observer before setting a value to the property...

Comment: Not sure what you are asking exactly. An observer's `job` is to get notified when a property changes. For sure you can avoid calls to observers by waiting till later to create them, as in the above example. A variation would be to have an observer which adds some other observer and maybe removes itself. With that in place you could  'avoid' the main observer on initial set of the property. Is that what you're going for?

Comment: Two quick questions 1. Should i need to removeObserver or it will be removed once the instance is destroyed? 2. How to check the observer is added on a property already?